# Excel VBA find string : Error 2015

Tags: vba, excel, find

I have to following code snippet ...

```
  Public Sub FindText(path As String, file As String)
    Dim Found As Range

    myText = "test("

    MacroBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    ' Open the File
    Workbooks.Open path & file, ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False
    For Each ws In Workbooks(file).Worksheets
     With ws

       Set Found = .UsedRange.Find(What:=myText, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

       If Not Found Is Nothing Then
        ' do stuff
        ' ...
```

I see in the debugger that Found contains Error 2015! The sheet contains the text I want in the formula.

Any ideas why I'm getting the error?

Thanks

Comment: it's because your formula in the sheet returns `#VALUE!` error. You can handle it using `IsError`: `If Not IsError(Found) Then`

Comment: is this a `sub` or `function`? please, show complete code.

Comment: Bravo Simoco, nice catch!

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers, they are not the same. Because of misunderstanding, developers use them interchangeably because in many cases there is no difference between function and sub. But there is fundamental difference- function is design to return value while sub to run action. Search more to understand it.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers, by default they do not do the same things. And not always you can use function and sub interchangeably. When treating VBA seriously you should understand the difference.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As follow up from comments to the Q, `Error 2015` occurs because your formula in the sheet returns `#VALUE!` error. You can handle it using `IsError`:

```
If Not Found Is Nothing Then
    If Not IsError(Found) Then
       ' do sth
    End If
End If
```

Comment: is there a way of finding which formula is giving the error?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use 'Set' in your code.  You only use this to assign a reference to an object.  Try:-

```
For Each ws In Workbooks(file).Worksheets
     With ws

       Found = .UsedRange.Find(What:=myText, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

       If Not Found Is Nothing Then
        ' do stuff
        ' ...
```

Hopefully this should work.

Comment: Unfortunately the debugger complains about that.  "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: Actually, "Found" is a Range, and ranges you normally need to "SET"... so Ruefuel is right on needing that part.