# Function returns Error 2015 when decimal symbol is comma

Tags: excel, vba

I have problems running my code under systems with comma as decimal symbol. If there is point(dot) as decimal - I have no problems.
My function calculates turnover by customer in certain period. Date is stored as week and day of week both in a single cell as a decimal number.
Is there any solution to get my function work with both decimal number formats?

Here is simplified code:

```
Sub Calculation()
    Dim Customer As String: Customer = "Customer1"
    Dim FromValue As Double: FromValue = 1.2 'week number 1 - Tuesday
    Dim ToValue As Double: ToValue = 6.4 'week number 6 - Thursday
    Debug.Print Formula1(Customer, FromValue, ToValue)
End Sub

Function Formula1(Customer As String, FirstDate, LastDate)
'Range ("G6:G100") contains quantity
'Range ("AD6:AD100") contains price per 1 piece
'Range ("A6:A100") contains customer's name
'Range ("K6:K100") contains week and day of week
Formula1 = Evaluate("=SumProduct(" & Range("G6:G100").Address & "," _
            & Range("AD6:AD100").Address & "," _
            & "--(ISNUMBER(FIND(" & Chr(34) & Customer & Chr(34) & "," & Range("A6:A100").Address & ")))," _
            & "--(" & Range("K6:K100").Address & ">=" & FirstDate & ")," _
            & "--(" & Range("K6:K100").Address & "<=" & LastDate & "))")
'=SumProduct($G$6:$G$100,$AD$6:$AD$100,--(ISNUMBER(FIND("Customer1",$A$6:$A$100))),--($K$6:$K$100>=1.2),--($K$6:$K$100<=6.4))
End Function
```

P.S. Sorry for my English

Comment: 1) just tested your code (I have comma as decimal separator) and it works 2) [Evaluate returns Error 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22014093/excel-vba-find-string-error-2015/22015934#22015934) when cell, that involved in calculations, has error `#VALUE!` - so, check content of your cells in ranges `G6:G100`, `AD6:AD100` and so on. 3) why do you using `Evaluate("=SumProduct(" & Range("G6:G100").Address & ","...)` when you could simply use `Evaluate("=SumProduct(G6:G100...")`?

Comment: Even this simple code return error 2015 when decimal is comma. `code` Sub Calculation()
    Dim FromValue As Double: FromValue = 1.2
    Debug.Print Evaluate("=SumProduct(A1:A10,--(B1:B10>=" & FromValue & "))")
    Debug.Print "=SumProduct(A1:A10,--(B1:B10>=" & FromValue & "))"
End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself. Problem was in data type - if data type of FromValue and ToValue is Double function works only with point as decimal. When I change data type to text - function works with both - comma and point as decimal symbol.