# VBA Vlookup with Match across variable workbook Error 438

Tags: vba, runtime-error, match, vlookup

Good afternoon everyone,

I have been getting an error 438 - Object doesn't support property or method for the following.

```
Cells(4 + Counter, i * Cells(2, 3).Value) = 
  Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(2, i * Cells(2, 3).Value).Value, 
                                        Workbooks(file).Range("$E$1:$N$20"),  
  Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(3, i * Cells(2, 3).Value).Value,  
                                      Workbooks(file).Range("$E$1:$R$1"), 0), False)
```

Basically I have a file that is downloaded to my computer from a program outside of Excel - a CSV. In previous code I search for the latest file (the downloaded file), import to Excel, with each time the file being named something different. I then have cell B1 display the file name (so i can reference this later). I have file = Range("B1").value and set this to a string.

In this opened file I need to search for a term and return several values to the right of this cell. I have decided that each returned value should be treated differently as the headers may change and thus I am using Match. After the process has retrieved the data I have in the second file, I then set the counter to increase so that next time I import data the new retrieved data goes to the row below, thus effectively creating a time series. The columns are set the way they are because I have to retrieve 6 data points for several groups, with number of groups and possible data points fluctuating. Cells(2,3).Value is the number of data points I need to retrieve so effectively I can create a template where each group is placed across the worksheet and each group's data is place down the worksheet.

I'm not sure whether it is in the syntax of my expression or otherwise, but what apparently seems to be correct has got me stumped. Once I can get it down I can then extend it to the other variables I need to bring in for all groups.
Many thanks!

Comment: Think i worked it out: Workbooks(file).Range("$E$1:$N$20") does not refer to a sheet. I have defined the ranges as a separate variable and then included the sheets references and it does not produce error any more.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough code/description for me to understand fully where you are putting the data that you copy. I am a little confused with the code portion given as to source and destination references.

Things to be clear on:

- Source versus destination
- Referencing the worksheet in the source and
  the destination (you have now commented on this. You were only partially qualifying)
- Error handling in case value being searched for is
  not present

I am assuming you already have a loop set up so you can adjust the following example which demonstrates some of the relevant syntax:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
Dim file As Workbook
Dim strPath As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim counter As Long
Dim i As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Adjust to where you are copying data too/assumes file name is in same sheet

strPath = "C:\Folder\"  'Location of CSVs

'Assume you have an actual loop set up
counter = 1 'Put here so example has a start value
i = 1 ' Put here so example has a start value  

If IsFileOpen(strPath & ws1.Range("B1").Value & ".csv") Then
    MsgBox "File already in use! Please close."
    Exit Sub

Else

   Set file = Workbooks.Open(strPath & ws1.Range("B1").Value & ".csv")
   Set ws2 = file.Sheets(1)

   With ws2
    'Require a test for existence of value
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("$E$1:$N$20"),  .Cells(2,  i * .Cells(2, 3).Value).Value) > 0 Then
           ws1.Cells(4 + counter, i * .Cells(2, 3).Value) = 
           Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
           .Cells(2, i * .Cells(2, 3).Value).Value, _
           .Range("$E$1:$N$20"), _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(.Cells(3, i * .Cells(2, 3).Value).Value, .Range("$E$1:$R$1"), 0), _
           False)
      End If

  End With

  file.Close SaveChanges:=False

End If

'Loop

'Tidy away variables e.g. set wb = nothing .....

End Sub

'Source of function: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291295/macro-code-to-check-whether-a-file-is-already-open

Function IsFileOpen(filename As String)
Dim filenum As Integer, errnum As Integer
On Error Resume Next   ' Turn error checking off.
filenum = FreeFile()   ' Get a free file number.
' Attempt to open the file and lock it.
Open filename For Input Lock Read As #filenum
Close filenum          ' Close the file.
errnum = Err           ' Save the error number that occurred.
On Error GoTo 0        ' Turn error checking back on.

' Check to see which error occurred.
Select Case errnum

' No error occurred.
' File is NOT already open by another user.
     Case 0
       IsFileOpen = False

' Error number for "Permission Denied."
' File is already opened by another user.
     Case 70
       IsFileOpen = True

' Another error occurred.
     Case Else
       Error errnum
End Select

End Function
```

Personally i prefer the sort of construct using Find shown here in the response given by Mat Richardson:
[Excel VBA find string[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22014093/excel-vba-find-string-error-2015)

You can use Find to return the Range address of the search text and store in a variable, test if variable IS NOTHING, and use offset to get values to right.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
It seems The fixing of the workbook address solved the problem as well as defining the ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.
It seems The fixing of the workbook address solved the problem as well as defining the ranges.
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As String
Dim y As String

x = Range("B1")
y = Range("C1")

LookupRange = Workbooks(x).Sheets(y).Range("$E$1:$N$20")
HeaderRange = Workbooks(x).Sheets(y).Range("$E$1:$R$1")

I basically loop through, using a changing reference cell to search in the most recent file downloaded, and return a value that corresponds to a certain heading.
Regarding error handling. I think the process breaking is sufficient to alert me something is wrong. It should only break a variable cannot be found in the lookup. I have a predefined range containing the variables in the second sheet, that I look through.
The workbook is open through the macro and remain open while the process is working then it closes, so handling if the workbook is/is not open should not be a real issue.
Thanks for your help