# VBA Evaluate Formula Row Limit

Tags: vba, excel

- I have two data column with 900.000 rows
- Each cell has a string
- Some cells has equals values

First column range name is "D" and it range is A1:A900000.

Second column range name is "S" and it range is B1:B900000.

I want to evaluate them this way:

```
dataSheet.evaluate("IF(D=""DISPENSER"",S,FALSE)")
```

But, when column has more than 255 rows, evaluate returns "error 2015".

If these columns has more than 255 rows and I change the formula to

```
dataSheet.evaluate("IF(A2:A256=""DISPENSER"",B2:B256,FALSE)")
```

It works fine, but return me only the first 255 evaluated rows.

I got so many ways to workaround, but can't find a way to use all column as reference.

A code example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Example()

Dim arr As Variant

Dim formula As String


dataSheet.Columns("A").Name = "D" 'DISPENSER COLUMN
dataSheet.Columns("B").Name = "S" 'SELLER COLUMN


formula = "=IF(D=""DISPENSER"",S,FALSE)"

arr = filter(Application.Transpose(dataSheet.Evaluate(formula)), False, False)

'CODE USING FILTER ARRAY

End Sub
```

Please assume that in the

**Dispenser** column has this values: "DISPENSER" and "OLD DISPENSER", randomly.

**Seller** column has "S" and the row number.("S1", "S2", [...])

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with this? We might be able to suggest a different approach since this just seems like the first step of a process

Comment: can't replicate on my end,  please add more code.  My tests do the full column if asked.

Comment: I want to transpose the evaluate result and use it as an array.

Comment: If there is any [`#Value` or other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22014093/excel-vba-find-string-error-2015/22015934#22015934) Error Value in *any* cell in that column, you may expect an error from the Evaluate method.

Comment: The array can get up to `65535` cells.

Comment: @DavidZemens there is no error or blank cells in these columns, I checked it all.

Comment: @Vityata I can't get more then 255 cells, that is the problem. 65535 would be fine using a simple FOR workaround with a minimal speed loss.

Comment: Side note: you should probably not use variable names which mirror built-in function names such as `filter`.

Comment: do not use the same name as a function.  Change `Dim filter as variant` to something else.

Comment: `formula = "=IF(D=""DISPENSER"",S,FALSE)"` - you are missing the `=` sign in the formula.

Comment: @DavidZemens Used just for an example.

Comment: OK, but it's a bad example :)

Comment: @Vityata Tried it before, keep returning "error 2015".

Comment: @KauêDelmonte - I guess that `"IF(D=""DISPENSER"",S,FALSE)"` should be an array formula? Then there is some 255 limit, that should be taken into account for the old versions of Excel. https://www.google.com/search?q=array%2Bformula%2Blimits%2B255

Comment: I still do not get any errors or limits with your test code.

Comment: @Vityata Searching for a solution for my problem, I saw that is a characters limit to evaluate string, coincidentally is a **255** characters, but I don't see how this has a relation with my case.

Comment: @ScottCraner which excel version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Latest, Office 365 Excel.  32bit.

Comment: The limit to Transpose is not just number of items but size also.  If there is a lot of information in the cells being transposed then it will also truncate the output.

Comment: @ScottCraner First of all the evaluate is returning "error 2015" if I print it.

Comment: If you are getting an error they you need to look at the data.  There is nothing wrong with the formula or the Evaluate.

Comment: You know if evaluate function has a problem with special characters or anything like this?

Comment: @ScottCraner I guess not. If I loop throught all rows - steping 254 for each loop - I get no errors. However I'll check again my data and try use simple data (like "D1", "D2", [...]) to test the evaluate function.